# Fetching contributions SVG image from Github throws CORS error in a website created using Angular

Tags: angular, cors

I am trying to learn Angular by developing a website and I am getting the following error when I am trying to **HTTP get** my Github contributions from Github and showing them on the website.

`Failed to load https://github.com/users/kapil5harma/contributions: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://kapil5harma.netlify.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I am able to see it working on my local using CORS plugin for Chrome, but when the same code is deployed on the website, it is throwing the error mentioned above.

Comment: You must configure your server to allow requrest from another origin.

Comment: GitHub have an API you can use instead which should allow CORS

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790051/how-to-create-cross-domain-request

Comment: @Fussel I do not understand. I do not have any server. I just created a website using Angular CLI and deployed it to a domain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768418/how-to-make-cors-enabled-http-requests-in-angular-2/36768488

Comment: https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/how-to-handle-cors-in-an-angular2-and-node-express-applications-eb3de412abef

Comment: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular-2-spring-boot-jwt-cors_part1/

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/7xzsw0/angular_and_cors/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944242/how-to-use-cors-in-angular2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202347/angular2-to-rest-webapi-cors-issue?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389422/cors-issue-in-angular2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196915/angular-2-http-post-returns-data-but-goes-to-error-cors/44198143

Comment: @Milad I do not have a server and most of the links you shared seem to make changes in API on the server end.
I can not make changes to Github server.

Comment: @user184994 let me check it, this one seems a bit different.

Comment: how about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705726/github-api-and-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @Milad I'm still not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Github has its own dedicated API endpoints that serve the data you try to get. Check out [the Github API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/) for more info.

Comment: I am looking into API documentation, but I cannot find anything related to getting contributions SVG for a particular user.

Comment: Is it possible to get contributions SVG image from Github API?

Comment: If it's not listed in https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user, it is very unlikely that that specific information is available.

Comment: I checked it in docs plus I actually fetched data from their API, but it does not contain what I need.

Comment: In that case you're pretty much out of luck. You could still ask GitHub to extend their API to include the resources you'd like to access.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I have already emailed their support service asking for help. If not resolved, I would ask them for what you suggested. :)